# System of inequations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, systems-of-equations

> If $p$, $q$, $r$, $s$ and $t$ are real numbers such that $q+r<s+t$, $r+s<t+p$, $s+t<p+q$ and $p+q<r+s$, then find the largest and the smallest term among them.

This is how I solved it:

$$p+q<r+s$$
$$(+)-p-t<-s-r$$
Gives $q<t$

$$p+q<r+s$$$$(+)-p-q<-s-t$$
Gives $t<r$
$$s+t<p+q$$$$(+)-s-t<-q-r$$
Gives $r<p$

So we have $$p>r>t>q>s$$ or $$p>r>s>t>q$$ or $$p>r>t>s>q$$

So it's either $s$ or $q$ which is the smallest. Now I've to check which is smaller. For that,

$$q+r<s+t$$$$(-)s+r<p+t$$
Gives $q-s<s-p$

But $p<s$ as we have already seen before. So, $s-p<s-s$, hence, $q-s<s-s=0$
Gives $q<s$.

So $p$ is largest, $q$ is smallest.

**Please show any better or shorter or more elegant or unexepected ways to solve such a question.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rewrite the inequalities like this:

$$q+r<s+t<p+q<r+s<t+p$$

From this, we immediately see:

$$\begin{array}{c}q<t\\r<p\\q<s\\t<r\\s<p\end{array}$$

(Say, concentrate on the letter $p$ and find two expressions containing $p$: $p+q<t+p$ - cancel $p$ and conclude $q<t$. Similarly, now concentrate on the letters $q$, $r$, $s$, $t$ in turn.)

Or, in a tidier form:

$$\begin{array}{rcccl}q&<&t<r&<&p\\q&<&s&<&p\end{array}$$

which tells us that $q$ is the smallest and $p$ is the largest.